# How I compare two picturebox arrays?

Tags: c#, .net

I've been working on this app for long time. It has its flaws, like, instead of using arrays, I could use 2d array, but it is difficult to get in the next row without messing somethings up. I have 6 arrays of pictureboxes on one side and same thing on other. On the bottom I have array of available pictures that get be the right combination. The problem occurred when I tried to compare the right combination with the one that user selected. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            if (pb0.Image.ToString() == pb24.Image.ToString())
            {
                nizKomb[0].Image = Image.FromFile(@"Slike\crvena.png");
            }

            if(pb1.Image.ToString() == pb25.Image.ToString())
        {
            nizKomb[1].Image = Image.FromFile(@"Slike\crvena.png");
        }
            if(pb2.Image.ToString() == pb26.Image.ToString())
        {
            nizKomb[2].Image = Image.FromFile(@"Slike\crvena.png");
        }
            if(pb3.Image.ToString() == pb27.Image.ToString())
        {
            nizKomb[3].Image = Image.FromFile(@"Slike\crvena.png");
        }



        btnOK2.Visible = true;
        ctrl = 1;
    }

    private void btnOK2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (boxes2[i].Image.RawFormat == kombinacija[i].Image.RawFormat)
            {
                nizKomb2[i].Image = Image.FromFile(@"Slike\crvena.png");
            }

        }

        if (boxes2[0].Image == null || boxes2[1].Image == null || boxes2[2].Image == null || boxes2[3].Image == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unesite kombinaciju.");
        }
        else if (boxes2[0].Image != null && boxes2[1].Image != null && boxes2[2].Image != null && boxes2[3].Image != null)
        {
            btnOK3.Visible = true;

            ctrl = 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would advise against comparing Images. And against using ToString here! both are terribly slow and unreliable. Instead you should store the necessary information when you load the images, maybe put the file names into the pbox.Tag.

Comment: Work like you said, I put values in tags and compared them by it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to tackle this again, I have a C# class called TransparencyMaker that converts a Jpeg or Png file to a PixelInformationDatabase.

The code is here:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/TransparencyMaker

The part that would help you achieve this is:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/TransparencyMaker/blob/master/TransparencyMaker/MainForm.cs

If scroll about 3/4 of the way down the page, a method LoadPixelDatabase and LoadPixelDatabaseEx is the same thing but it accepts a BitMap parameter.

A PixelInformation database is just a List of PixelInformation objects, and a PixelInfomation class is listed here:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/TransparencyMaker/blob/master/TransparencyMaker/Objects/PixelInformation.cs

Basical a PixelInfo is just an object that contains the RGB Values, X & Y values, plus some info like the Total, which is just sum of RGB, and a few others:
[image]

Then if you wanted to compare your two databases, which I do when I erase by drawing a line. I erase a virtual image, than I find the pixels that were just mofified, and I apply the changes to the real image.

Here I find the pixels that were just modified because I draw a line in a color that is not in the image.

```
// Reload the PixelDatabase
PixelDatabase pixelDatabase = LoadPixelDatabaseEx(bitmap);

// Now get the pixels that are equal to the lineColor
List<PixelInformation> pixels = pixelDatabase.Pixels.Where(x => x.Color == LineColor).ToList();
```

Then you can just iterate your two lists to find any pixels that are different and you know you have changes if you find any.

I need to document the help for Transparency Maker. Any volunteers are welcome.

Data Juggler
[www.datajuggler.com](https://www.datajuggler.com) (all my open source projects are listed here).